# Using XDebug from terminal (got only SSH access)

Tags: php, debugging, vim, terminal, xdebug

When I develop with the server on my workstation I can use XDebug from my IDE and debug variables, etc.

Many times the server is on a remote machine where I have only SSH, so I only edit with vi. In that case is there a way to use XDebug? Is there a client I could use from terminal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use X forwarding with ssh, if allowed at the server end (see the *ForwardX11Trusted* directive for the server's ssh configuration file).  On your client you would start ssh using the *-X* argument to allow X forwarding.  This requires the client to support X (e.g. if your local machine is running Linux, OS X, etc...)

Comment: Sounds like something that could actually work, but it's not practical at all. I'll wait a few days before marking it accepted. Thanks :)